# Calculate column medians with NA's

Tags: r, na, median

I am trying to calculate the median of individual columns in R and then subtract the median value with every value in the column. The problem that I face here is I have N/A's in my column that I dont want to remove but just return them without subtracting the median. For example

```
ID <- c("A","B","C","D","E") 
Point_A <- c(1, NA, 3, NA, 5) 
Point_B <- c(NA, NA, 1, 3, 2)

df <- data.frame(ID,Point_A ,Point_B)
```

Is it possible to calculate the median of a column having N/A's? My resulting output would be

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | Point_A | Point_B |
+----+---------+---------+
| A  | -2      | NA      |
| B  | NA      | NA      |
| C  | 0       | -1      |
| D  | NA      | 1       |
| E  | 2       | 0       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I've edited to numeric values if you don't mind.

Comment: @David Not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     mutate_each(funs(median=.-median(., na.rm=TRUE)), -ID)
```

Comment: Great suggestion. What if I have more than 1 ID column.  like ID_A, ID_B, ID_B. How do I use that in the mutate_each function?

Comment: @Sharath There are options in `?select` i.e. `starts_with`, `matches` etc to match the column names and subset those columns/remove those.

Comment: @Sharath you can do stuff such as `-ID_A:ID_C`,

Comment: @David, akrun , Thank you so much. I got it working with ease now. :-)

Answer (score 6):

If we talking real `NA` values (as per OPs comment), one could do

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) x - median(x, na.rm = TRUE))
df
#   ID Point_A Point_B
# 1  A      -2      NA
# 2  B      NA      NA
# 3  C       0      -1
# 4  D      NA       1
# 5  E       2       0
```

Or using the `matrixStats` package

```
library(matrixStats)
df[-1] <- df[-1] - colMedians(as.matrix(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

When original `df` is

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), class = "factor"), Point_A = c(1, NA, 3, NA, 5), Point_B = c(NA, 
NA, 1, 3, 2)), .Names = c("ID", "Point_A", "Point_B"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen `matrixStats`. Cool!

Comment: @AlexA. this is package fully written in C++. Very efficient for matrices. In this case it was just as an alternative approach.

Comment: @David, That worked!! but when I have multiple ID columns. How do I modify your script?

Comment: @Sharath, simple. For example `indx <- !grepl("ID", names(df)) ; df[indx] <- lapply(df[indx], function(x) x - median(x, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

```
median(df[,]$Point_A, na.rm = TRUE)
```

where df is the data frame, while df[,] means for all rows and columns. But, be aware that the column the specified afterwards by $Point_A. The same could be written in this notation:

```
median(df[,"Point_A"], na.rm = TRUE)
```

where once again, df[,"Point_A"] means for all rows of the column Point_A.

Comment: `df` is the same as `df[,]`. While this presents a good start, it's an incomplete answer since you address only a single column and don't mention subtracting the median from the column. If there is more than one column (as is the case in the question) you can duplicate this median approach for each column, but that becomes cumbersome and eventually unfeasible as the number of columns grows.