# R: Calculate the column medians by grouping the ID's

Tags: r, dplyr, na, median

Continuing from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954124/calculate-column-medians-with-nas), Now I want to group by ID (only for Column 3) and calculate the median of the column (Point_B) and then subtract the median value with every value in the column (Point_B) to its respective group. NA's should still be returned.

Note: I want the ID grouping applied to only the Point_B column and not to Point_A as I want to calculate the median of the entire Point_A column and subtract it with the values in Point_A.

For example

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C") 
Point_A <- c(1,2,NA,1,2,3,1,2,NA) 
Point_B <- c(1,2,3,NA,NA,1,1,1,3)

df <- data.frame(ID,Point_A ,Point_B)


+----+---------+---------+
| ID | Point_A | Point_B |
+----+---------+---------+
| A  | 1       | 1       |
| A  | 2       | 2       |
| A  | NA      | 3       |
| B  | 1       | NA      |
| B  | 2       | NA      |
| B  | 3       | 1       |
| C  | 1       | 1       |
| C  | 2       | 1       |
| C  | NA      | 3       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

The solution provided to my previous post calculates medians without grouping by ID. Here it is

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     mutate_each(funs(median=.-median(., na.rm=TRUE)), -ID)
```

Desired Output

```
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | Point_A | Point_B |
+----+---------+---------+
| A  | -1      | -1      |
| A  | 0       | 0       |
| A  | NA      | 1       |
| B  | -1      | NA      |
| B  | 0       | NA      |
| B  | 1       | 0       |
| C  | -1      | 0       |
| C  | 0       | 0       |
| C  | NA      | 2       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

How do we get the values in Column3 with grouping by ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a `group_by`, I guess (following @docendodiscimus' suggestion):

```
demed <- function(x) x-median(x,na.rm=TRUE)

df %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(demed),Point_A) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  mutate_each(funs(demed),Point_B)
```

giving

```
  ID Point_A Point_B
1  A      -1      -1
2  A       0       0
3  A      NA       1
4  B      -1      NA
5  B       0      NA
6  B       1       0
7  C      -1       0
8  C       0       0
9  C      NA       2
```

---

I prefer the analogous `data.table` code. Its syntax requires writing the variable names multiple times, but has far fewer parentheses:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[,Point_A:=demed(Point_A)
][,Point_B:=demed(Point_B)
,by=ID]
```

Comment: Frank, Thanks for the suggestion but my desired output is a bit different. I have shown it above. I need to take medians and subtract with each value in the column. Could you please check that?

Comment: Thanks for the edited code. But the Point_A column seems unchanged. Can we do it together or do I need to do it separately for each Point_A & Point_B columns?

Comment: I want to group the medians for Point_B column only. Please check my desired output.

Comment: @Sharath You'll have to define your de-median function before the piping, but this gets the job done with fairly nice syntax.

Comment: Outstanding work. I got the result with your new edit. Thank you so much. I applied it to a bigger dataset and it works like charm.

Comment: IMO, the dplyr approach should be `df %>% mutate(Point_A = demed(Point_A)) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Point_B = demed(Point_B))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus The thing I like best of dplyr (that I've noticed so far) is the anonymous functions with `.`. They make it easier to read (like, did we make `Point_A2`?...better look closely) and avoid typos (like accidentally typing `Point_a`). But yeah, your way is probably the idiomatic one.

Comment: If you prefer to use `mutate_each` in this case, I'd make a slight adjustment to make it cleaner imo: `mutate_each(funs(demed),Point_A)`